# Git checkout -b, branch already exists

Tags: git, github

When I'm merging two branches and they can't be merged automatically Github provides these instructions:

**Step 1: From your project repository, bring in the changes and test.**

```
git fetch origin
git checkout -b master origin/master
git merge develop
```

**Step 2: Merge the changes and update on GitHub.**

```
git checkout develop
git merge --no-ff master
git push origin develop
```

But, in this case, the branch `master` already exists locally, and the line `git checkout -b master origin/master` returns this message:

```
git checkout -b master origin/master
fatal: A branch named 'master' already exists.
```

Is the correct thing to do in this case to replace that line with `git checkout master`? I've wondered this for a while, bit worried about what `git checkout master` might do as opposed to with `-b`.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If `master` doesn't exist, then after this line

```
git checkout -b master origin/master
```

`master` will be a branch pointing to the same commit as `origin/master`.

If you already have a `master` branch, it might be out of date with `origin/master`, so simply writing

```
git checkout master
```

isn't quite enough. You'll also want to run

```
git merge origin/master
```

afterward to bring `master` up to date (typically this will just be a fast forward).

Comment: Can also add `--ff-only` to *only* fast forward and bail out instead of creating a merge commit